# How to prevent building if integration test was failed?

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I've got the following test:

```
public class AppITCase

{

    @Test
    public void failTest() {
        fail();
    }
}
```

It just fails. But if I run `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test`, I will see this:

```
Results :

Failed tests:
  AppITCase.failTest:16

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent! The file encoding for reports output files should be provided by the POM property ${project.reporting.outputEncoding}.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.853 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-14T01:32:16+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/141M
```

**Important lines:**

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
```

What? Why maven accepted this build, if it had test failures? How to solve this?

**UPD**
If I run `mvn verify`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]

[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ vsjws-samples ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ vsjws-samples ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.333 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-14T01:41:23+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/200M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven-failsafe-plugin Failures and BUILD SUCCESS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279160/maven-failsafe-plugin-failures-and-build-success)

Comment: Also of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614374/error-during-failsafe-integration-test-does-not-cause-failed-maven-build, the tldr there being that you should do `mvn verify` and not `mvn failsafe:integration-test`

Comment: But no. mvn verify didn't even run the test as I can see. Still 'BUILD SUCCESS'

Comment: `mvn clean verify` The output logs you got are weird, considering the failsafe plugin did not even run...